# One To Many Relationship in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to understand "one to many relationships". Let's assume I have two tables: `Person` and `Vehicle`.

In the `Person` table, I have 2 columns: `personid` and `personame`. `personid` is the `primary key`. I have 2 rows in the `Person` table:

```
personid | personname
---------+-----------
1        | Rajesh
2        | Suresh
```

In the `Vehicle` table, I have 2 columns: `vehicleid` and `vehiclename`. I have one row in the `Vehicle` table

```
vehicleid | vehiclename
----------+------------
1         | Car
```

Now, as per "one to many relationships" each person can have zero, one, or many vehicles.

So, can both `Rajesh` and `Suresh` be mapped to `Car`?

For example:

```
Rajesh -+- Car
Suresh -/
```

In "one to many relationships", can 2 different `Person`s refer to the same `Vehicle`? Or should each `Vehicle` only be mapped to a single `Person`?

In "many to one relationships", the only car in the `Vehicle` table can be mapped to multiple persons in the `Person` table, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need a Many-to-many "relationship". It's actually a combination of 2-One-to-many relationships.  The only way to do this in sql, is to have a third table.

**Person**
PersonID
Name

One - to - many (One person can own many vehicles)

**Ownership (Or Title?)** 
PersonID
VehicleID

many-to-one (vehicle can have many owners)

**Vehicle**
vehicleid 
vehiclename

The ownership table has a potential row for any user / vehicle combination (And should probably make that combination a primary key or at least a unique constraint).

Other fields can be put in the ownership table such as purchase date and amount, sale date and amount, etc. Because those pertain to the ownership of the vehicle and not a property of the owner or vehicle itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is inconsistent, you say "*each person can have zero, one or many vehciles*", but then you ask "*now can both Rajesh and Suresh be mapped to Car* ?", which implies each vehicle can have multiple Owners, *not* that each person can have multiple vehicles...

Assuming to want to restrict ownership of each vehicle to a single person (In practice, a vehicle can be owned by multiple individuals), and allow an individual to own multiple cars, simply add a `PersonId` to `vehicle` table, to indicate or point to the individual who owns that vehicle.

So your vehicle table would then be

```
vehicleid OwnerId vehiclename
    1        1       'Ford'
    2        1       'Maserati'
    3        1       'BMW'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for my inconsistent question. As per One to Many relationship based on the table mentioned by you can't the table be                                                                        
vehicleid OwnerId vehiclename
    1        1       'Ford'
    1        2       'Ford'   
Now owner1 has vehicle 'Ford' and owner2 has vehicle 'Ford'.In the owner point of view each owner is having relationship with car. And in One to Many if a 'Ford' is linked to owner1 cant it again be linked to owner2 .why cant owner2 be linked to the car if it is already linked with owner1

Comment: It can, but then it's one to many from car to owner, not owner to car.  i.e., cars can be owned by multiple individuals, but each individual is limited to one car.  In real world, relationship between cars and owners is many-to-many.  Cars can be owned by multiple owners, and a single individual can own multiple cars.

Comment: And one more question If my One to Many relationship is from Owner to Car. Cant the Owner1 and Owner2 be mapped to Car ?. I mean to say      OwnerId   vehicleid  vehiclename
              1        1       'Ford'
              2        1       'Ford'

Comment: NO,  if owner1 and owner2 are both mapped to a single car, that is manyOwners-to-OneCar, many-to-one, not one-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

If Rajesh and Suresh both have the same vehicle and each of them can possibly have more than 1 vehicle, then you have a Many-to-Many Relationship.

But if a vehicle can only be owned by one person, then you have a One-To-Many Relationship from Person to Vehicle.

> In One to Many relationship can 2 different persons refer to the car
>   in vehicle table

no. 2 is not One.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. Yes my question is In One to Many relationship can 2 different persons refer to the only car in vehicle table ? .If not why is that . And as per One to Many relationship terminology one person can have one or more cars. So now Rajesh is referring to the car and Suresh is also reffering to car . Is this not correct

Comment: when you're dealing with One-To-Many Relationships and Many-To-One Relationships, then it is always important where the relation originates. When you have a One-To-Many from Person to Vehicle, then each Person can have multiple vehicles, but each vehicle can only be owned by 1 Person.

Comment: The easiest way to implement the One-To-Many Relationship from Person to Vehicle is adding a column like "owner_id" in vehicle that holds the id of the Person. Since you can only have one id in this column, this explains why a vehicle can only be owned by one person.

Answer (score 0):

From the Vehicle perspective, it has 1 (one row, the "Car Row") to Many Person rows (assuming Person table had a VehicleId column)

Answer (score 0):

`Many to One` vs `One to Many` refers to the same concept, just viewed from different sides. (either from vehicle or person).

In a standard One To Many here you would have

A person table and a vehicle table where the vehicle table contains a personId with a FK to the person table. This will let you model a person with 0 or many vehicles owned by a single person uniquely.

If a vehicle has multiple owners you should introduce a many to many relationship between person and vehicle. That would require a third table (PersonVehicle)

Answer (score 0):

In your example Rajesh and Suresh can share a same car to do this you need car primary key in person table.

Rajesh has one relationship with CarA
Suresh has one relationship with CarA

And CarA will have many relationship(Rajesh & Suresh).

Answer (score 0):

> Now, as per "one to many relationships" each person can have zero,
>   one, or many vehicles.

Correct.

> So, can both `Rajesh` and `Suresh` be mapped to `Car`?

No, not in a "one to many relationship". This would be a "many to many relationship".

> In "one to many relationships", can 2 different `Person`s refer to the
>   same `Vehicle`? Or should each `Vehicle` only be mapped to a single
>   `Person`?

Each `Vehicle` should only be linked to a *single* `Person`.

> In "many to one relationships", the only car in the `Vehicle` table
>   can be mapped to multiple persons in the `Person` table, correct?

Yes, but each `Person` would then only be able to be linked to a *single* `Vehicle`.

"Many to one" and "one to many" are the same thing, just in reverse. So, the following two statements are equivalent:

1. **One** `A` can link **to many** `B`s.
2. **Many** `B`s can link **to one** `A`.

Notice how "one to many" and "many to one" are in each (bold), and how, in order to mean the same thing, the tables `A` and `B` are switched?

## Examples

Assuming the following:

```
Person      Vehicle
------      -------
Jane        Car
John        Truck
```

### One to one

`Jane` is linked to `Car`. Each `Person` can only be linked to *one* `Vehicle` at a time, and vice-versa.

```
Jane--------Car
John        Truck
```

### One to many

`Jane` is linked to `Car` *and* `Truck`. Each `Vehicle` can only be linked to *one* `Person` at a time. Each `Person` can be linked to multiple `Vehicle`s.

```
Jane---+----Car
John    \---Truck
```

### Many to one

`Jane` *and* `John` are linked to `Car`. Each `Person` can only be linked to *one* `Vehicle` at a time. Each `Vehicle` can be linked to multiple `Person`s.

```
Jane----+---Car
John---/    Truck
```

### Many to many

Each `Vehicle` can be linked to multiple `Person`s, and vice-versa.

`Jane` *and* `John` are *both* linked to `Car` *and* `Truck`.

```
Jane---+--+-Car
        \/
        /\
John---+--+-Truck
```

`Jane` is linked to `Car` *and* `Truck`, and `John` is linked to `Truck`

```
Jane---+----Car
        \ 
John-----+--Truck
```